# How to extract values from dataframe to use in conditional formatting while applying it on certain select categories or data entries at a time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, xlsxwriter

[within the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTtdN.jpg) I am trying to calculate median and standard deviation but it allows me to calculate only one column at a time I want means to calculate for all three columns at once then it stores the data into another dataframe I want to know how to use values from those specified in conditional formatting and apply it only to its corresponding category

[Dataframe df9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPH69.jpg)
[DF for Median](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzQBP.jpg)

Comment: can u share the dataframe? So that I can help

Comment: ok if that is the case make a sample dataframe with dummy data and give the dataframe. Without dataframe I really can't

Comment: Yogesh i have added them in the form of images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you want to use a single groupby to perform computations on `Month1` `Month2` and `Month3` columns? For instance the `mean - std` and `mean + std` you have at the bottom of your code?

Here is a way you can do that :

```
np.random.seed(87) # Use this for reproducibility

df9 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,(10,5)),\
      columns = ['Month1','Month2','Month3','Revised Category','useless column'])

agg = df9[['Month1','Month2','Month3','Revised Category']].\
      groupby('Revised Category').agg(lambda x: [x.mean()-x.std(),x.mean()+x.std()])

agg = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_items(zip(agg.index, agg[col].values)).T for col in agg],axis=1)
agg.columns = ['Month1_low','Month1_up','Month2_low','Month2_up','Month3_low','Month3_up']
```

And the output is:

```
    Month1_low  Month1_up   Month2_low  Month2_up   Month3_low  Month3_up
0   -0.414214   2.414214    -0.414214   2.414214    -0.207107   1.207107
1   -0.207107   1.207107    -0.207107   1.207107    -0.207107   1.207107
2   0.183475    2.149859    0.105573    1.894427    0.663340    2.336660
```

The index in this new `agg` dataframe represents yours categories. Therefore if you want to access, say `Month1_up` for category `0`, just slice: `agg.loc[0,'Month1_up']`.

If you want to compute the mean for all of your months at once, what you can do is concatenate your original dataframe before a groupby, like this:

```
concatenated = pd.concat([df9[[col,'Revised Category']].rename({col:'Month'},axis = 1) \
                          for col in ['Month1','Month2','Month3']])
concatenated.groupby('Revised Category').agg(lambda x: [x.mean()-x.std(),x.mean()+x.std()])
agg2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(zip(agg2.index, agg2.Month.values)).T
agg2.columns = ['Months_low','Months_up']

    Months_low  Months_up
0   -0.149859   1.816525
1   -0.047723   1.047723
2   0.344018    2.100426
```

EDIT:

I'm not use to coloring dataframes so this solution might be heavy and underoptimal, but it worked on an example.

First, let's regroup the original data from `df9` and the data we computed with `groupby` (with upper and lower bounds):

```
months = ['Month1','Month2','Month3']
conc2 = pd.concat([df9.set_index('Revised Category')[[col]].join(\
        agg[[col+'_low',col+'_up']]) for col in months],axis = 1)

    Month1  Month1_low  Month1_up   Month2  Month2_low  Month2_up   Month3  Month3_low  Month3_up
0   2       -0.414214   2.414214    0       -0.414214   2.414214    0       -0.207107   1.207107
0   0       -0.414214   2.414214    2       -0.414214   2.414214    1       -0.207107   1.207107
1   1       -0.207107   1.207107    0       -0.207107   1.207107    0       -0.207107   1.207107
```

We will use this to create a mask to code where the value in one of the `Month` columns is above the corresponding upper bound.

This mask will then be used to apply the wanted colors to the style of the dataframe.

```
mask = conc2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x[col]<x[col+'_low'] for col in months]),axis = 1)

mask.columns = months # the columns names need to be the same as conc2 for apply below

    Month1  Month2  Month3
0   False   False   False
0   False   False   False
1   False   False   False
```

Now that we have created our boolean mask, we need to replace its values by the corresponding color messages understood by the `style` object in pandas.

```
mask = mask.reset_index(drop = True).apply(lambda x: x.map(\
       {True:'background-color: red',False:'background-color: None'}))
```

And now that we have those strings in our mask, we just have to apply it to our dataframe's style to print it in color.

```
conc2[months].reset_index(drop = True).style.apply(lambda x: mask, axis=None)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this but the other part of the problem is, how do i use this for selective conditional formatting, for example, taking values of Month1_low and Month1_up for Category 0 and putting conditional formatting on values belonging only to Category 0 in the data?

Comment: Also if I want to do the above mean-std/ mean+std computation for all 3 months's data together, what's the solution? ie. 1 value of mean+std for all 3 months and 1 value of mean-std for all 3 months.

Comment: I edited to add a way to groupby and take all your months at once, though there are other ways to do it. What do you mean by conditional formatting? And by 'data' you mean `df9` or the dataframe I called `agg`?

Comment: by conditional formatting i mean setting up a criteria mean-std<x<mean+std and whenever x is out of this range it should get highlighted as red text, but this should get applied category wise, i.e. month_up of category 0 gets applied only to values corresponding to category 0, by "data" i mean df9.

Comment: I'm not use to conditional formatting, so my way of doing it might not be pythonic, but it's a starter. Please tell me if it worked on your dataframe.

Comment: I am unable to understand the code you shared, could you please explain the logic or alternatively submit your complete code?

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain it, it makes a really long post, but I hope it's clear now.

Comment: what if I wanted to color data other than the original dataframe 'df9', which has similar structure i.e. has Category column and another column onto which I want to apply the colors on category by category basis taking the 'Month_low' and 'Month_up' values from our calculation?

Comment: Please help me understand the masking process. Starting from line with code months=....